# Fire ng change on change of checkbox checked value in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Changed the value but change event is not getting triggered.I want to trigger the change when ischecked is changed

in html

```
 <input class="inputStyle" type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked"  id="actA" tabindex="0" (change)="onAct($event)">
```

have another function(in ts)

```
onChangeoption(lang) {
            this.isChecked = true;     `enter code here`   
 }
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: I have some logic on onchange.if the checkbox is checked the logic will be execute.But i changed the check box value outside of on change so on change logic is not working

Comment: try this [(ngModel)]="isChecked"

Comment: tried ng model its not calling ngchange...

Comment: is there any way to call ngchange from another function

Comment: ok try without the 2 way binding [ngModel]="isChecked" (ngModelChange)="onAct($event)"

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is trigger a `change` event after you have programatically changed the value of the input first and this is not going to work.

I can suggest two approaches:

**Approach 1:**
From what you have shown in those snippets, it seems easy to call `onAct` inside the `onChangeoption`. If you don't really need the change event object, you can call `onAct` immediately after you change the value of `isChecked`.

**Approach 2:**
If you need the change event object, create a reference of the `input` element and programatically dispatch a `change` event

In your TypeScript code:

```
  @ViewChild('myCheckbox') myCheckbox;

  onChangeoption() {
    this.isChecked = true; `enter code here`
    this.myCheckbox.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
```

And update your template:

```
<input #myCheckbox class="inputStyle" type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked"  
 id="actA" tabindex="0" (change)="onAct($event)">
```